# I can visit any website BUT the google search website

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns

Somehow, out of the blue when starting my day I started getting errors when trying to search things by typing them into the chrome searchbar. I got the same error when manually typing in www.google.com or www.google.nl, I tried Firefox, opera, safari, edge...all the same error.

Every other website I visit works fine, my phone is able to access google.com on the same wifi network. I updated the router, the devolo power adapter, basically everything. I renewed the local DNS as well, restarted a lot of times...no fix yet. Both on ethernet cable as on the WIFI, the same, below shown problem:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> www.google.nl uses an unsupported protocol.
>   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH HIDE DETAILS Unsupported protocol
>   The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or
>   cipher suite.

Other google sites like youtube, and play.google.com work fine by the way.

As per comment, I checked the HTTPS cert that I get when visiting youtube, and when inspecting I find a multidomain cert for the following domains:

> DNS Name=*.google.com DNS Name=*.android.com DNS
>   Name=*.appengine.google.com DNS Name=*.cloud.google.com DNS
>   Name=*.gcp.gvt2.com DNS Name=*.google-analytics.com DNS
>   Name=*.google.ca DNS Name=*.google.cl DNS Name=*.google.co.in DNS
>   Name=*.google.co.jp DNS Name=*.google.co.uk DNS Name=*.google.com.ar
>   DNS Name=*.google.com.au DNS Name=*.google.com.br DNS
>   Name=*.google.com.co DNS Name=*.google.com.mx DNS Name=*.google.com.tr
>   DNS Name=*.google.com.vn DNS Name=*.google.de DNS Name=*.google.es DNS
>   Name=*.google.fr DNS Name=*.google.hu DNS Name=*.google.it DNS
>   Name=*.google.nl DNS Name=*.google.pl DNS Name=*.google.pt DNS
>   Name=*.googleadapis.com DNS Name=*.googleapis.cn DNS
>   Name=*.googlecommerce.com DNS Name=*.googlevideo.com DNS
>   Name=*.gstatic.cn DNS Name=*.gstatic.com DNS Name=*.gvt1.com DNS
>   Name=*.gvt2.com DNS Name=*.metric.gstatic.com DNS Name=*.urchin.com
>   DNS Name=*.url.google.com DNS Name=*.youtube-nocookie.com DNS
>   Name=*.youtube.com DNS Name=*.youtubeeducation.com DNS
>   Name=*.ytimg.com DNS Name=android.clients.google.com DNS
>   Name=android.com DNS Name=developer.android.google.cn DNS Name=g.co
>   DNS Name=goo.gl DNS Name=google-analytics.com DNS Name=google.com DNS
>   Name=googlecommerce.com DNS Name=urchin.com DNS Name=www.goo.gl DNS
>   Name=youtu.be DNS Name=youtube.com DNS Name=youtubeeducation.com

Running Bitdefender 2017 that is coming up clean.

Comment: This indicates you have software installed and/or hardware on your network that is performing a Man In The Middle attack on your connection.  In other words you are being send the incorrect certificate for google.com  Chrome has specific protection for all their domains.  The fact this effects Firefox which has its own certificate store, indicates, the problem is your security software.

Comment: What could be a path to fixing this?

Comment: I just told you.  You have security software installed on your PC that is causing this.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, thought you meant it as in a virus installed, I'll look into it thanks :)

Comment: It could be a virus.  Of course, I suspect all your https traffic is insecure at this point, Google just goes the extra mile on their domains.  *I don't believe that YouTube is https only.*

Comment: Thanks, I added my findings to the question. Considering my antivirus is coming up clean, what is left for me to do?

Comment: You disabled the security feature to scan your HTTPS traffic?

Comment: Well that worked :) Even though the cause is still unclear to me, a bug in Bitdefender then? Concluding, turning off Bitdefender's SLL Scan fixed it, thanks again :)

Comment: Of course it did.  Bitdefender was giving you an invalid self-signed certificate.  As I pointed out Google goes to the extra step on their end (and Chrome) and basically rejects invalid secure connections.